# How to get the separating hyperplane in OpenCV SVM?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

I am trying to get the hyperplane associated with an SVM. For simplicity sake, let use assume the [example in OpenCV's page](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/ml/introduction_to_svm).

Here, they are constructing an "image" using a collection of sample outputs in the following way:

```
// Show the decision regions given by the SVM
Vec3b green(0,255,0), blue (255,0,0);
for (int i = 0; i < image.rows; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < image.cols; ++j)
    {
        Mat sampleMat = (Mat_<float>(1,2) << j,i);
        float response = svm->predict(sampleMat);

        if (response == 1)
            image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)  = green;
        else if (response == -1)
            image.at<Vec3b>(i,j)  = blue;
    }
}
```

The line between the green and blue classes is shown as the separating hyperplane.

Now, my question is: how do I obtain this line as a vector of points or a cv::Mat to do further processing?

Comment: Do you need to find out the hyperplane coordinates from the image, or mathematically from the svm parameters?

Comment: Mathematically from the SVM parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the getSupportVector function to retrieve the support vectors, and the getDecisionFunction function to retrieve the scalar bias of the decision function.

I assume that you want the separating frontier only for a linear svm, because the non linear case is much more complex.

In this case, the separating plane is given by an equation of the type W*X+b=0.
You can easily find the W and b parameters: the sum of all the support vector give you W, and b is the value returned by getDecisionFunction(0).

The code to compute the W vector should look like (untested) :

```
    Mat W(sv.cols, 1, CV_32F, 0);
    for(int r=0; r<sv.rows; ++r)
    {
        for(int c=0; c<sv.cols; ++c)
        {
            W.at<float>(c)+=sv.at<float>(r,c);
        }
    }
```

Once you have the equation of the line, in the case of the OpenCV example, you can display it on the image, by doing something like (again, untested):

```
    Point pt1(0, b/W.at<float>(1));
    Point pt2(b/W.at<float>(0));
    line(image, pt1, pt2, color);
```

The pt1, pt2 points come from the line equation for x=0 and y=0.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking for the weighted support vectors of the cv::SVM class and I realized that in the new 3.0 API, the `getSupportVectors()` gives the weighted support vectors themselves.